# how to insert a matrix in the middle of another matrix

Tags: python, matrix, insert

I am working in Python.
I have a matrix called Y = np.random.rand(10,10)  and a matrix called X=np.zeros ((5,5)).
I define:
y_insert=2
x_insert=3
I want to insert matrix X on Y on position (x_insert,y_insert). So the result should be a 10 by 10 matrix filled with random numbers except between (2,3) and (6,7) where the matrix should contain 0.
How can that be achieved?

So far I have tried:

```
Y = np.random.rand(10,10)
X=np.zeros ((5,5))
y_insert=2
x_insert=3
insert matrix X on Y on position (x_insert,y_insert)
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is address the sub-matrix of `Y` you want to override and then assign `X` to it:

```
Y[x_insert : x_insert + 5, y_insert : y_insert + 5] = X
```

Or, for a more general case:

```
Y[x_insert : x_insert + X.shape[0], y_insert : y_insert + X.shape[1]] = X
```